# Field Update using a formula to render a date that is 14 business days after the close won date

Tags: formula

I am creating a process builder to field update a date field (Requested Start Date) that should be 14 business days after the Close Date. The field I'm updating is a date field and so is the field I'm referencing in the formula.

> I am receiving an error: "The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect
>   parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Date, received Text"

My formula:

```
IF(
    MOD( [Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate  - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7) > 2,
    [Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate + 20,'',
    IF(MOD( [Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7) > 0,
        [Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate + 19,''
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have excess parameters in your `IF()` function, and one of them is the wrong type.

Indentation can often help to show these parameter-count and grouping problems:

```
IF(
    MOD([Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate  - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7) > 2,
    [Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate + 20,
    '',
    IF(
        MOD([Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7) > 0,
        [Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate + 19,
        ''
    )
)
```

`IF()` takes exactly three parameters: a condition, a value if it's true, and a value if it's false. Your outermost `IF()` has four parameters, and your inner `IF()` has three (as is correct).

Both `IF()` expressions are receiving mixed data types. Your true parameter (the second one) is a Date value. But the third, which is superfluous on the outer `IF()`, is an empty string. You probably want `null` in that position for the inner `IF()`.

Your formula ought to compile if you make those changes:

```
IF(
    MOD([Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate  - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7) > 2,
    [Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate + 20,
    IF(
        MOD([Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7) > 0,
        [Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate + 19,
        null
    )
)
```